# How to set deployment path on web projects in Visual Source Safe 6.0

Tags: visual-sourcesafe, sourcesafe-6.0

I am using Visual Source Safe 6.0.

I set Shadow Folder option for one of my PHP project.

Now I want to use the Deploy Feature of VSS. How can I set this up? I have seearched many times but failed to retrieve satisfactory answer. Details are as follows:

VSS project Name: mC
Virtual Root: `<none>`

I have two web sites where I want to deploy my VSS project from VSS. Details of the Web Sites are as follows:

Server: HostGator
Server UserName: usrname
Server Password: usrpassword
Server URL: mc.com
Folder where to Deploy in my Site: public_html

I tried the following as the Deployment path but it says "Failed to Login"

'ftp://usrname:usrpassword@mc.com/usrname/public_html'
'ftp://usrname:usrpassword@mc.com/usrname/public_html/'
'ftp://usrname:usrpassword@mc.com/~/public_html'
'ftp://usrname:usrpassword@mc.com/~/public_html/'
'ftp://usrname@mc.com/usrname/public_html'
'ftp://usrname@mc.com/usrname/public_html/'
'ftp://usrname@mc.com/~/public_html'
'ftp://usrname@mc.com/~/public_html/'

(without the single-quotes)

What can I try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make sure your usrpassword does not contain any special characters. Because special characters such as comma(,) , at (@) , colon (:) etc. bears a different meaning in this system.

Then use the following structure for file upload:

ftp://usrname:usrpassword@mc.com/public_html

You can use multiple ftp sites by separating them using a comma (,).